# Dependence of posterior probability on parameters

Tags: statistical-inference, bayesian, bayes-theorem

From page 88, *Introduction to Probability* (2019 2 edn) by Jessica Hwang and Joseph K. Blitzstein.

> 27. Suppose that there are $5$ blood types in the population, named type $1$ through type $5$,
>     with probabilities $p_1, p_2,\cdots ,p_5$. A crime was committed by two individuals. A suspect,who has blood type $1$, has prior probability $p$ of being guilty. At the crime scene, blood
>     evidence is collected, which shows that one of the criminals has type $1$ and the other
>     has type $2$.
>
> Find the posterior probability that the suspect is guilty, given the evidence. Does the evidence make it more likely or less likely that the suspect is guilty, or does this depend on the values of the parameters $p, p_1,. . . , p_5$? If it depends, give a simple criterion for when the evidence makes it more likely that the suspect is guilty.

What I got so far is that P(guilty|evidence) = P(evidence|guilty)P(guilty)/(P(evidence|guilty)P(guilty)+P(evidence|not guilty)P(not guilty)).

P(guilty) = p

P(not guilty) $= 1 - p$

P(evidence|guilty) = 1/2 because one criminal has blood type 1

P(evidence|not guilty) = 1/5 because there are 5 blood types.

So I get P(guilty|evidence) $= \dfrac{0.5p}{0.5p + 0.2(1-p)}$ and I do not know if this is correct.

Comment: Do you understand how to use Baye's theorem to calculate conditional probabilities?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Comment: @5xum I edited to show where I am at so far and where I am stuck at.

Comment: @TonyS.F. I edited to show what I calculated so far but do not know how to continue.

Comment: Okay what you have so far seems good to me. Now, to answer the qualitative question of whether the evidence makes it more likely that the suspect committed the crime you must compare the posterior probability you calculated to the prior, which was $p$, and determine if/when the posterior will be greater than $p$.

Comment: @TonyS.F. Is it right to say that p(evidence|not guilty) = 1/5 because the question does not say that the probability of each blood type is equal. How do I address this?

Comment: Good catch, in fact it is not okay to say $p(evidence | not guilty) = \frac{1}{5}$. That would be for uniformly distributed blood types, which you noted we do not have.

Comment: @TonyS.F. What distribution would I be able to use in this case?

Comment: To be honest I am not so sure, I think either $p_1$ since it is the probability that blood type $1$ showed up or $p_1+p_2$ since both blood type 1 and 2 showed up.

Comment: @TonyS.F. Ok. Thanks. I'll see if anyone else can chime in

Answer (score 2):

$\mathit G$: event that the suspect with blood type 1 is guilty
$\mathit E$: event that  the suspect's blood type matches one of the blood types found at the crime scene

We want to calculate $\mathbf P(G\vert E)$

Using Baye's theorem,

$\mathbf P(G\vert E) = \frac{\mathbf P(G)\mathbf P(E\vert G)}{\mathbf P(E)} $

$\mathbf P(G) = p$

$\mathbf P(E) = \mathbf P(G)\mathbf P(E\vert G) + \mathbf P(G^c)\mathbf P(E\vert G^c) $

$\mathbf P(E\vert G)$ is the probability that the suspect's blood type matches one of the blood types found at the crime scene i.e. type 1 and 2, given that the suspect with blood type 1 is guilty. Or simply that the probability that the suspect's blood type was found at the crime scene given that he is guilty. If the suspect is guilty, his blood type with definitely be at the crime scene. So this probability amounts to one.
$\mathbf P(E\vert G) = 1$

$\mathbf P(E\vert G^c)$ is the probability that the suspects blood type matches the ones found in the crime scene, given that he is not guilty. In other words, the probability that the suspect has the same blood type as one of the criminals. This would amount to $\frac{p_1}{p_1 +\,p_2}$

This gives us the following result,

$\mathbf P(G\vert E) = \frac{p}{p\, +\,(1-p)\cdot\frac{p_1}{p_1 +\, 
 p_2}} $

Answer (score -1):

What I understand as the evidence is one of the criminals has type 1 and the other has type 2. So if our suspect having type 1 blood is guilty the probability of this evidence occurring is 1.

P(evidence|guilty)=1

And if not guilty the evidence has probability $2p_1p_2$ (both blood types occurring and order not important)

P(evidence|not guilty)=$2p_1p_2$

Hence we get $\frac{p}{p+2p_1p_2(1-p)}$

Comment: Why would P(evidence | guilty) = 1? Since if the suspect is guilty, shouldn't other possible evidences be considered (e.g. evidence of criminal of type 1 and criminal of type 3)?