# Conditional Probability, Blitzstein, Problem 27, Chapter 2: Blood type, crime, probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

From page 88, *Introduction to Probability* (2019 2 edn) by Jessica Hwang and Joseph K. Blitzstein.

> 27. Suppose that there are $5$ blood types in the population, named type $1$ through type $5$,
>     with probabilities $p_1, p_2,\cdots ,p_5$. A crime was committed by two individuals. A suspect,who has blood type $1$, has prior probability $p$ of being guilty. At the crime scene, blood
>     evidence is collected, which shows that one of the criminals has type $1$ and the other
>     has type $2$.
>
> Find the posterior probability that the suspect is guilty, given the evidence. [Rest of question is omitted.]

I am fully aware of these two other posts

- [Dependence of posterior probability on parameters](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2628053)
- [The conditional probability of the evidence on a crime scene?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3499763)

where the solution is discussed, however, I don't understand what is going on. In fact, there seem to be $3$ different answers. Hence, I wish to repost the problem.

##### My attempt:

Let $E$ be the event that the suspect is guilty.
Let $B$ be the event that the blood type of suspect matches blood type $1$, i.e. one of the samples found in the crime scene.
Let $E^c$ be the event where the suspect is not guilty.
Let $p_1$ be the $p$ (blood type $1$).

Therefore, by invoking Bayes, we have:
$P(E \mid B) = \frac{P(E)P(B \mid E)}{P(E)P(B\mid E))+ (P(E^c)P(B\mid E^c)}$

This gives: $P(E\mid B) = \frac{p}{p+(1-p)p_1}$

Both posts cited above, however, states a different answer. **Where am I going wrong in my thinking?** In my opinion, given that the suspect is not guilty, then $P(B\mid E^c)$ reduces to just being $p_1$, the naturally occurring probability of the blood type.

Comment: Typesetting tip:  If you meant to write $P(E \mid B)$, type `$P(E \mid B)$`.

Comment: You're not conditioning on all of the evidence provided in the problem. The problem states that type #1 and type #2 blood was found at the scene of the crime. This evidence was not taken into account in your calculations

Comment: But the evidence that type #2 blood was found is immaterial, given that I know that the blood type of the suspect is type #1.

Comment: Not sure about that. When you condition on the event that only type #1 and type #2 blood was found at the scene, you eliminate the possibility that any individual of type #3, #4, #5 blood committed the crime, which makes a difference since blood types occurs with (possibly) varying proportions.